# Diagnosing causes of android database lagging

Tags: android, performance, android-database

I have an android database and the same call to the database sometimes takes >100 ms and sometimes 2 seconds. 
My app doesn't do anything different. 2 Seconds aren't really acceptable. 
How do I track down the source of the lag?

Comment: If you're sharing database connection (basically, using same open-helper) then one operation might be blocked until another one completes.

Comment: Also, define the "same" call. If you're selecting something from table by some parameter, it might be linear search issue.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where in your Java code the lag comes from. Use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to determine if there is anything that you can do to optimize the database access. Beyond that, you would need to provide your code to illustrate what the "call" is.